# SVG shapes with fill, stroke and strokewidth

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I have a polygon shape with border, stroke-width and fill colors.

I am looking for multiple polygon shapes; below is one of them with 4 edges. Out of which 3 edges just have stroke and the other edge has fill color.

[image]

From above figure we have one side of the polygon with fill and stroke, others just stroke with strokeWidth 1.

I am quite new to SVG. What can be the best way to draw this shape?

Paths, lines, polygons, or combination of this? Will fill-rules be helpful here? Suggestions please.

Comment: Draw this with InkScape, then massage the output to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of paths and rectangles will likely be what you end up with. I find it easier to fill explicitly because it is easier to manipulate directly with JavaScript if needed.

Here is one solution. I find when working SVG keeping things as simple as possible will make your life much easier.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:se="http://svg-edit.googlecode.com" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" width="777" height="480" style="">                                    
  <title>my vector image</title>                                                                                                 <g class="currentLayer" style="">
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect fill="#4a90d6" stroke="#222222" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-dashoffset="" fill-rule="nonzero" id="svg_1" x="8" y="8" width="13" height="74" class="selected"/>
  <path fill="#4a90d6" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#222222" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dashoffset="" fill-rule="nonzero" opacity="1" marker-start="" marker-mid="" marker-end="" d="M 20.8456 8.25316 L 87.1747 7.74683" id="svg_5" class="selected"/>
  <path fill="#4a90d6" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#222222" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dashoffset="" fill-rule="nonzero" opacity="1" marker-start="" marker-mid="" marker-end="" d="M 21.0987 81.924 L 119.073 80.4051" id="svg_9" class="selected"/>
  <path fill="#4a90d6" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#222222" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dashoffset="" fill-rule="nonzero" opacity="1" marker-start="" marker-mid="" marker-end="" d="M 86.162 6.98734 L 118.061 79.6456" id="svg_14" class="selected"/>
  </g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Can both be paths ?. During transitions I want to convert those strokes to filled shapes. I mean the three edges. @RandyCasburn

Comment: (a) A three paths are unnecessary here. You only need one path. (b) Yes, there is no reason you can't use paths for both the filled and unfilled edges.

Comment: yes ... all can be paths. I just threw this together quickly to give you a starting point.